# Указатель на тип char

Tags: c++, массивы, строки, указатели

Я как-то давно спрашивал по поводу указателей, разобрался, всем ответившим спасибо. Но сейчас мне пришлось столкнутся с типом `char`:

```
int *a;
char *b;

a = new int(10);
b = "bla bla bla"; // Странно ведь мы записываем в адрес, а не в разыменованный указатель

cout << "a: " << *a << endl; // Выведет значение, а без * адрес (логично и понятно)
cout << "b: " << b << endl; // Выведет значение всего того что мы засунули в "адрес" указателя, почему так, если приводить аналогию с int то почему тут не как там?
```

Хотелось бы понять, как работает указатель на тип `char` (хотелось бы увидеть аргументированные ответы, почему так различается, и что-то от себя как рекомендации). Шерстил интернет — по теме указателей в C++ ничего не нашел

P. S.: Прошу прощения, если эта тема всех достала или мое сообщение является дубликатом (есть темы похожие, но, вроде, это не то, что мне надо).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Давайте рассмотрим предложения из вашего примера шаг за шагом.

В этом предложении

```
int *a;
```

вы объявили переменную `a` как указатель на объект с типом `int`

В этом предложении

```
char *b;
```

вы объявили переменную `b` как указатель на объект с типом `char`

В этом предложении

```
a = new int(10);
```

был создан объект в динамической памяти типа `int`, который был инициализирован значением 10.

В этом предложении

```
b = "bla bla bla";
```

в левой части выражения с оператором присваивания стоит переменна с типом `char *`. В правой части этого выражения используется строковый литерал `"bla bla bla"`. Строковые литералы в C++ имеют типы константных символьных массивов.

(C++ Стандарт, 2.14.5 String literals)

> 8 Ordinary string literals and UTF-8 string literals are also referred
>   to as narrow string literals. A narrow string literal has type
>   **“array of n const char”**, where n is the size of the string as defined below, and has static storage duration (3.7).

Строковый литерал `"bla bla bla"` имеет тип `const char [12]`. В выражениях массивы неявно преобразуются к указателям на свой первый элемент.

Согласно стандарту C++ (4.2 Array-to-pointer conversion)

> 1 An lvalue or rvalue of type “array of N T” or “array of unknown
>   bound of T” can be converted to a prvalue of type “pointer to T”. **The
>   result is a pointer to the first element of the array**.

Таким образом в приведенном предложении в правой части выражения с оператором присваивания используется значение типа `const char *`, которое указывает на первый символ строкового литерала `"bla bla bla"`. То есть имеет место попытка указателю типа `char *` присвоить значение указателя типа `const char *`. Так как не существует неявного преобразования из типа указателя на константный объект в тип указателя на неконстантный объект, то компилятор должен выдать диагностическое сообщение.

Правильно было бы объявить переменную `b` следующим образом

```
const char *b;
```

Тогда вышеприведенное предложение с присваиванием было бы корректно, и переменной `b`  был бы присвоен адрес первого символа строкового литерала, стоящего в правой части выражения от знака присваивания.

Данное предложение

```
b = "bla bla bla";
```

фактически, эквивалентно следующему предложению

```
b = &"bla bla bla"[0];
```

В этом предложении

```
cout << "a: " << *a << endl;
```

целочисленное значение, адресуемое указателем `a` выводится на консоль.

Было бы более корректно записать

```
cout << "*a: " << *a << endl; 
        ^^^
```

В этом предложении

```
cout << "b: " << b << endl;
```

при условии, что компилятор каким-то образом сгенерировал объектный модуль, несмотря на ошибку, о которой я сказал выше, выведет на консоль строковый литерал, так как для указателей типа `char *` оператор `operator <<` перегружен таким образом, что вместо значения самого указателя, он выводит содержимое памяти, адресуемое этим указателем, как строку.

Если вы хотите вывести на консоль именно значение самого указателя, то вам в таком случае следует написать либо

```
cout << "b: " << ( void * )b << endl;
```

либо

```
cout << "b: " << static_cast<void *>( b ) << endl;
```

А если переменная `b` была объявлена с квалификатором `const`, то

```
cout << "b: " << ( const void * )b << endl;
```

либо

```
cout << "b: " << static_cast<const void *>( b ) << endl;
```

Comment: а что будет если я напишу так *b = "bla bla2";
и при выводе напишу *b

Comment: @MaximPro Извините. Переменная b у вас объявлена как char *. Поэтому *b имеет тип char и присваивание указателя типа const char * скалярного типу char сгенерирует ошибку компиляции.

Comment: @MaximPro Кроме того вы не выделили память, куда вы хотите поместить значение. То есть указатель b неинициализирован.

Comment: ну понятно что инициализация нужна как самособой разумеющаяся, не совсем понятно почему нельзя

Comment: @MaximPro Потому что это разные типы и нет неявного преобразования из одного типа в другой. Обычно размер адреса составляет 4 или 8 байтов, тогда как размер объекта типа char всего лишь 1 байт. Поэтому непонятно, как хранить адрес в объекте типа char. Вы можете использовать кастинг, но все равно в этом большого смысла нет.

Comment: можно про вот это подробнее? b = &"bla bla bla"[0];
и как мне вывести адреса каждого символа из этого "константного массива"

Comment: @MaximPro Как уже было написано, строковый литерал - это массив. Поэтому к нему можно применить оператор индексирования. Выражение "bla bla bla"[0] предоставляет первый символ этого литерала, а затем применяется оператор &, который возвращает адрес этого первого символа строкового литерала.

Comment: а что насчет вывода адресов каждого из этих символов строкового литерала?

Comment: @MaximPro  Можно сделать так: const char *p = "bla bla bla"; while ( *p ) std::cout << ( const void * )p++ << std::endl;

Comment: @MaximPro Или, если включить еще адрес нулевого символа, то const char *p = "bla bla bla"; do std::cout << ( const void * )p << std::endl; while ( *p++ );

Comment: а вот если я напишу так cout << &b << endl; мне выведет адрес...начала строкового литерала?

Comment: @MaximPro Это адрес переменной b.

Comment: точно, хех. А да и почему используется void а не int: "cout << "b: " << ( void * )b << endl;"

Comment: @MaximPro Потому что для void * определен оператор <<

Comment: всмысле? не совсем понимаю, я пробовал подставить int тоже работает, void это же неопределенный тип?

Comment: @MaximPro void * и void - разные типы.

Comment: ухх, и в чем различие? что-то уже совсем несет в дебри похоже мне стоит что-то почитать! Не посоветуете а то я вас уже достал своими вопросами

Comment: @MaximPro Вы можете задать отдельные вопросы на форуме.

Comment: эмм пожалуй воздержусь, и все таки в чем различие этих типов? в том что там неопределенность а в другом указатель на неопределенный тип?

Comment: @MaximPro Указатель - это завершенный тип.

Comment: хорошо, я вроде так и понял вобщем я пошел курить мануал (если что задам вопрос на форуме, а вы ответите :D)

Answer (score 6):

Вы столкнулись со специальным поведением строковых литералов в C и C++.

Дело в том, что строковой литерал `"bla bla bla"` есть константа типа <s>`const char*`</s> `const char [12]` [спасибо @Pavel Mayorov за уточнение] (12 получается из 11 символов и дополнительного нуля в конце), и в вашем контексте преобразуется к *указателю* на первый символ этой самой строки/массива, расположенной компилятором где-то в программе. То есть, *тип* выражения `"bla bla bla"` есть `const char [12]`, и неявно преобразуется в `const char*`.

Далее, `cout` имеет специальное поведение для указателей на символ: он воспринимает их как строки, а не как «обыкновенные» указатели, и выводит все символы за первым аж до финального `\0`.

Это специальное поведение в C++ введено для совместимости с языком C, в котором нету «настоящих» строк. Вообще, `char` и `char*` в C++ во многом обладают особыми свойствами, дополнительными к указателям на другие типы.

Кстати говоря, странно, что ваш код скомпилировался без диагностики: типы `const char*` и `char*` не должны так просто присваиваться друг другу.

Comment: я понимаю, что в const char* невозможно изменить значение?почему когда мы пишем указатель в cout b он выводит все символы?

Comment: @MaximPro: Дописал ответ. По сути, в `const char*` лишь указатель на самый первый символ, а вот `cout` вывобит не только первый, но и все последующие до `\0`.

Comment: @MaximPro: в `const char*` невозможно изменить значение символов п оуказателю. Сам указатель поменять, понятно, можно.

Comment: VladD, `"bla bla bla"` - это не литерал указателя, а литерал массива! И он может быть как типа `char const[12]`, так и `char[12]`, в зависимости от компилятора.

Comment: @PavelMayorov: Насколько я понимаю, это литерал массива _только_ в синтаксисе `char[] text = "blablabla"`.

Comment: @PavelMayorov: Хотя да, его тип `const char[n]`, согласен.

Comment: Если мне не изменяет память, попытки изменить "bla bla bla" - undefined behavior.

Comment: @Arkady: Так и есть. Например, компилятор имеет право поместить строковые константы в защищённую от записи секцию памяти.

Answer (score 5):

Когда язык C только появлялся, указатели на символ использовались для работы с так называемыми нуль-терминальными строками - и по традиции используются до сих пор.

Поэтому в языках C и C++ указатель на символ - это обычно строка. И библиотечные функции, работающие с `char*`, знают, что они работают со строкой.

Посмотрите на первую часть ваших выражений вывода на консоль:

```
cout << "a: "
cout << "b: "
```

`"a: "` и `"b: "` здесь тоже являются указателями на `char`. Но если бы вместо этих строк выводились их адреса, вы бы сказали, что это странно, не так ли? Тогда почему точно то же самое, но с использованием промежуточной переменной, удивляет?

Answer (score 3):

```
b = "bla bla bla"; /// Странно ведь мы записываем в адрес, а не в разименованный указатель
```

"bla bla bla" не записывается, это константа, b - получает только адрес первого символа этого массива.

```
cout << "b: " << b << endl; /// Выведет значение всего того что мы засунули в "адрес" указателя, почему так, если приводить анологию с int то почему тут не как там?
```

Это связано не с указателем на char, а с объектом cout. Так как char* часто представляет строки, то в cout определено для него именно такое поведение.